# RAM consumption by pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, brute-force

I am trying to work with around 100 csv files to do a time series analysis.
To build an efficient algorithm to use I've structured my data read_csv function such that it only reads all the files at once and don't have to repeat the same process again and again. To explain further following is my code:

```
start_date = '2016-06-01'
end_date = '2017-09-02'
allocation = 170000

#contains 100 symbols
usesymbols = ['']

cost_matrix = []

def data():
    dates=pd.date_range(start_date,end_date) 
    df=pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    for symbol in usesymbols:
        df_temp=pd.read_csv('/home/furqan/Desktop/python_data/{}.csv'.format(str(symbol)),usecols=['Date','Close'],
                            parse_dates=True,index_col='Date',na_values=['nan'])
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Close': symbol})
        df=df.join(df_temp)
        df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
        df=df.fillna(method='bfill')
    return df

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1))


power_set = list(powerset(usesymbols))

dataframe = data()
```

Problem is that if I run the above code with 15 symbols it works perfectly.
But that's not sufficient, I want to use 100 symbols.
If I run the code with 100 items in usesymbols, my RAM is used up completely and the machine freezes.

Is there anything that can be done to avoid this situation?

Edited Part:
1) I've 16 GB RAM.

2) the issue is with the variable power_set, if I don't call powerset function data gets retrieved easily.

Comment: Options 1: Get a machine with more RAM. Option 2: Use less RAM, i.e. process your data in a suitable chunk size and not all at once.

Comment: appendix to option 1: machine can be virtual.

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame.memory_usage(index=False)

Return:
sizes : Series
A series with column names as index and memory usage of columns with units of bytes.